# How do i resolve problem render view in Android 3.6

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.6

Anyone help me fix this problem. Recently, I upgraded Android 3.5 to 3.6, then the layout file reported an error:
`Render problem: Exception raised during rendering (Details)`.
Although I created a new project, as shown below, in the layout file there is only one TextClock view.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BclHV.png)

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.ContentResolver.registerContentObserver(ContentResolver.java:2263)
    at android.widget.TextClock.registerObserver(TextClock.java:626)
    at android.widget.TextClock.onAttachedToWindow(TextClock.java:545)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:19575)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:335)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:396)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:209)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:608)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:734)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Thank you

**EDIT**: It's Android Studio bug. See [issueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=TextClock%20render%20problem) for updated information.

Comment: Same situation. Probably problem with `TextClock`. I added stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

add this to build.gradle

```
android{
.....
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```